# Issues running MDX toolkit wrapped Swift 4.2 iOS application after Enterprise distribution. Exception Type: EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP) iOS 12.4

Tags: ios, swift, citrix, enterprise-distribution, xcode10.3

I am working on distributing my iOS application within the enterprise after wrapping the application with MDX toolkit. The application works on all my devices when I run it using Xcode but after the distribution the application crashes on launch on the company allocated devices. We are using Secure Hub for enterprise distribution.

The crash log files that I retrieved from the device are :

[image: crash logs 1]

[image: crash logs continued]

I also managed to collect device console logs and the console logs are as follows:

```
 Can't get most elevated app state from dictionary {
     BKSApplicationStateExtensionKey = 0; 
     SBApplicationStateDisplayIDKey = "my.app.NARMS.dev" 
     SBApplicationStateKey = 0;
     SBApplicationStateProcessIDKey =398; 
     SBApplicationStateRunningReasonsKey =     (
            {
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = 
Resume;
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 10000;
    },
            {
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionIdentifierKey = "FBSceneSnapshotAction:my.app.NARMS.dev";
        SBApplicationStateRunningReasonAssertionReasonKey = 4;
    }
);
```

}

***Please note that I had to convert a swift 3.0 project to swift 4.2 before facing this issue and also we are trying Enterprise distribution.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An Update to the above question: 
We decided to try out skipping the step where we wrap the .ipa file with MDX toolkit and that solved the problem for us.

So instead of the following steps:

1. Archive and generate .ipa
2. Wrap the .ipa with MDX toolkit to generate .mdx.
3. Distribute .mdx with XenMobile.

We did this:

1. Archive and generate .ipa
2. Distribute .ipa with XenMobile